# global pointer = this pointer in method

Tags: c++, pointers, methods, this

I do this:

```
act_level = this;
```

in a method of a class (e.g. myclass).
Act_level is a global pointer, declared like this:

```
myclass * act_level = NULL;
```

The act_level pointer is not declared twice, since I checked this several times. I declared it normally like above and wrote above myclass.cpp:

```
extern myclass * act_level;
```

When I run the program, at this point things get strange. In the Debugger it shows me that act_level is changing to the same value as the this pointer. Since I use VS2013 I can see the complete class in the act_level variable viewing thing (don't know how to describe but it definetly worked as I wanted it to)*edit: see the pic.
BUT leaving the method my global pointer act_level is not the pointer to my object, it stays the NULL-pointer.

While in the method in debug:
[before leaving method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K9Zb5.png)

In another part of the Program exactly after I leave the method:
[after leaving method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/756XY.png)

---

I want my global pointer to be changed to the pointer at my Object so I know which one I edited last. How do I do that properly and why is this not going?

Comment: If you see it in the complete class variable viewing thing, then it's not a global pointer. Maybe you have a duplicate declaration in your class that is hiding the global one?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] page soon.  Since C does not have a `this` pointer or classes, you must be discussing C++.  Do not dual tag C++ questions with C too (nor C questions with C++ too).  It irritates people and is unnecessary.

Comment: @RaymondChen He says "I can see the complete class in the act_level variable viewing thing", which I *think* means that he is looking at the "auto" tab in Visual Studio, and act_level has a value.  That would work even if act_level was a pointer.  But I still think your psychic debugging skills are working, and he has a duplicate declaration which is hiding the global one. (I can't believe I have just contradicted Raymond Chen by the way.)

Comment: My method only contains this:
`next = act_level;
 act_level = this;
 before = NULL;
 if (next != NULL)
  next->before = this;
 `
So I dont have a duplicated declaration...

Comment: This will cause undefined behaviour if the objected being pointed to is destroyed, and the you try to look at `act_level`

Comment: Nope, i adjust the act_level in the destructor of my class ;)